# Does the M2ePro list all products from Magento to Amazon?

Tags: magento-1.9, m2epro

Any one idea about **"Does the M2ePro list all products from Magento to Amazon?**"

I have found this Link and step by step  i have configured but last step showing errors,Please see attached screenshots. let me know how to fix this issue

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jEgMhGLDKA&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

Yes M2E Pro lists all products in Amazon if it is configured properly.

Please use the  [docs.m2epro.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=18188473](https://docs.m2epro.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=18188473) link for guideline.

Comment: Could you please give configured guideline link.

Comment: Hi @Bhargav, i have added my issue via screenshot,so please let me know how to resolve this..Thank you in Advance.